# LWJGL Matrix Stack Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, lwjgl

I wrote a simple class for matrix operations that was ported from C++ OpenGL to Java with LWJGL. However I have observed some odd behaviour that shouldn't occur at all. My pushMatrix() and popMatrix() seem to do nothing at all. When I run this code, the model I display will float off to the right of the screen. It should not move at all after translated because I pushed and popped the matrix stack. 
Here is my MatrixManager class:

```
private static Stack<Matrix4f> stack = new Stack<Matrix4f>();
public static void pushMatrix()
{
    stack.push(stack.peek());
}

public static void popMatrix()
{
    stack.pop();
}
public static Matrix4f getTop()
{
    return stack.peek();
}

public static void setTop(Matrix4f m)
{
    stack.set(stack.size()-1, m);
}

public static void multiplyTop(Matrix4f m)
{
    stack.set(stack.size()-1, Matrix4f.mul(stack.peek(), m,null));
}

public static void SendToGLSL()
{

    stack.peek().store(modelBuf);
    modelBuf.flip();
    //viewBuf.flip();
    //projectionBuf.flip();


    //GL20.glUniformMatrix4(matrixlocations[0], false, modelBuf);
    //GL20.glUniformMatrix4(matrixlocations[1], false, viewBuf);
    //GL20.glUniformMatrix4(matrixlocations[2], false, projectionBuf);
    GL20.glUniformMatrix4(matrixlocations[3], false, modelBuf);
}
```

And the code in question:

```
protected void renderTileEntityDirt(TileEntityDirt t)
{
    MatrixManager.pushMatrix();

    MatrixManager.multiplyTop(MatrixManager.getTop().translate(new Vector3f(t.posX,t.posY,t.posZ)));

    MatrixManager.SendToGLSL();
    Model.BindModelDataToRender(t.getClass());
    Main.renderEngine.bindTexture(TextureResource.getTexture("dirt"));
    Model.RenderModel(t.getClass());
    MatrixManager.popMatrix();
}
```

modelBuf is just a FloatBuffer.
matrixLocations[0] is the the matrix I use in GLSL.

Comment: Unrelated, but... you have a method called `setTop (...)` and `getTop (...)` yet your implementation of `multiplyTop (...)` is not using either of those methods. It looks like this could/should be implemented as `setTop (Matrix4f.mul (getTop (), m, null))` for consistency.

Comment: That said, I think the order of your operands in `Matrix4f.mul (...)` might be reversed (in other words, consider swapping `stack.peek()` and `m` in the arguments). I am not sure how your Matrix class is implemented, whether it's row-major or column-major, pre- or post-multiplication, but the order of operands could be responsible for unusual behavior like this.

Comment: I tried swapping them, but to no effect. I think the problem lies in the pushing and popping, because even if the order was reversed it should not move off the screen; it should lock at that position since we are pushing and popping the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```
stack.push(stack.peek());
```

you push the pointer for the matrix returned from stack.peek(); when you modify either of the two, it goes to the same slot in memory. e.g. When you modify the top of the stack, the second element is modified as well. Try:

```
stack.push(new Matrix4f(stack.peek()));
```

I had a similar problem working with JBox2D Vec2 at one point.